# How to interpret the output from the 'print_ring' command in monero-wallet-cli?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, transaction-data

My objective is to identify the true input of a transaction as the spender.

Simply keeping track of transaction hashes, in which I am the receiver, does not seem to help, as my own coin can be included in a ring as a decoy in other transactions.

I tried using the `print_ring <tx_id>` command in `monero-wallet-cli`, but am having trouble interpreting the results, which look as follows:

```
f6755e91a53485ddcaa7b1aa2132b101cedfdd32928780ba13c56aefff08dea9 absolute 17100 21558 25253 28804 28854 28932 28981 29049 29272 29292 29341 
915a22c9e3047a26305541c25ed1113f47ac90f9f3dba7a8578ad3ff06323fe7 absolute 11992 20083 21404 22989 24068 28325 28717 28860 29098 29132 29176
```

How can I use this information to discern the true input of the transaction?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I use this information to discern the true input of the transaction?

You can't. The output format for `print_ring` is:

```
K absolute N,N,...,N
...
```

Where K is the key image hex and each N is an absolute global output index of an output possibly being spent (e.g. a ring member). Each row represents an input of the tx.

This does not tell you *which* output is the real spend output.

You can use the cli command `incoming_transfers uses` to see the global index and uses of each of your owned outputs.